# Verificar se o numero digitado ja esta presente na struc

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, struct

Boa tarde, estou enfrentando o seguinte problema. Preciso fazer um algorítimo para o cadastro de contas bancarias de 15 pessoas com as seguintes informações: número da conta,nome e saldo. Porém é preciso verifcar se o número da conta ja foi digitado,se sim será impressa uma mensagem de erro se não ira solicitar o resto dos dados.

Só que não estou conseguindo fazer essa verificação, sempre esta dando a mensagem que o número ja existe mesmo não existindo. Segue meu codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 2

typedef struct {
    int num_conta;
    char nome[40];
    float saldo;
} Dados;

Dados Clientes[TAM];
int posConta = 0;

//Função para imprimir menu de opções
void Imprimir_Menu();

//Função para cadastrar clientes
void Cadastro(Dados *Clientes, int *pos);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int opcao;


    do {
        Imprimir_Menu();

        printf("Digite a opção desejada: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);

        switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                Cadastro(Clientes, &posConta);
                break;
        }
    } while (posConta != TAM);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

void Imprimir_Menu() {
    printf("MENU \n");
    printf("\t 1. Cadastrar contas; \n");
    printf("\t 2. Visualizar todas as contas de determinado cliente; \n");
    printf("\t 3. Excluir a conta com menor saldo; \n");
    printf("\t 4. Sair \n\n");
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

void Cadastro(Dados *Clientes, int *pos) {
    int Num_temp, i, achou = 0;

    printf("\n--------------------CADASTRO DE CLIENTES--------------------\n");

    printf("%dº Cliente \n", *pos + 1);

    /* O programa iria prosseguir somente quando o usuario digitar um número de conta
     que ainda não existe */

    do {
        printf("\tDgite o número da conta: ");
        scanf("%d", &Num_temp);

        for (i = 0; i < *pos + 1; i++) {
            if (Clientes[i].num_conta == Num_temp) {
                printf("achou = %d \n", achou);
                achou = 1;
            }
        }
        if (achou = 1) {
            printf("Conta ja existente. Favor digitar um número diferente. \n");
        }
    } while (achou != 0);

    Clientes[*pos].num_conta = Num_temp;

    printf("\tDgite o nome do cliente: ");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    gets(Clientes[*pos].nome);

    printf("\tDigite seu saldo: ");
    scanf("%f", &Clientes[*pos].saldo);

    *pos = *pos + 1;


    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Segue a saída do programa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `if (achou = 1)`. O compilador faz milagres. Sempre compile o código e preste extrema atenção aos avisos, pois 99.99% deles são erros. Naturalmente o código tem outros problemas, mas estou me a focar apenas no que foi citado

Comment: O mais importante do comentário do @Isac é que o código tem vários problemas.

Comment: Ja imaginava, to aprendendo estes conteúdos por conta própria durantes as minhas ferias da faculdade, para ter uma boa base no 2º Período. Mesma assim orbigados a todos que me ajudaram a encontrar o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Bom amigo pelo que eu vi na condição If(achou = 1), você faz achou receber 1, e não achou==1

Comment: Nem acredito q era so isso, tava um tempão presso nisso kk brigadão Victor!

Comment: Você tá em qual semestre da faculdade? Por que pelo que estou vendo tem bastante erros no seu código.

Comment: to indo pro segundo

Comment: Bom, estou no quinto semestre... Já ganhei duas vezes em primeiro lugar a maratona de programação da minha faculdade... Se precisar de ajuda pode me enviar e-mail ou mensagem.

Comment: Não dispenso não Victor, mt obrigado. Como você tem mais experiência que eu, o que você acha que preciso melhoar em meus codigos? Qual erro mais encontrado no meu codigo acima?